# How do I stretch a block in height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The parent unit `.wrapper` has a height of 100%. The height of the child `.info` block is not defined and may be different. How to stretch a child block `.wrp` for the entire remaining height of the parent block `.wrapper`?

Аssociation: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568460/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5)

Any other options?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.wrp {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"></div>
  <div class="info">Did you see the virgin on the rock <br>in a white robe over the waves<br>When, raging in the stormy darkness, <br>the sea Played with the shores,<br>When a ray of lightning lit up<br>Her hourly brilliance with scarlet <br>and the wind beat and flew<br>With her flying veil?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) layout to easily do this job.

- Parent element should have `display: flex;` and [`flex-direction: column;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- The child that you want to  fit the remaining space of the parent should have [`flex: 1;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrp {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.info {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"></div>
  <div class="info">Did you see the virgin on the rock <br>in a white robe over the waves<br>When, raging in the stormy darkness, <br>the sea Played with the shores,<br>When a ray of lightning lit up<br>Her hourly brilliance with scarlet <br>and the wind beat and flew<br>With
    her flying veil?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var height_wrapper = $('.wrapper').height(),
  height_info = $('.info').height(),
  height_wpr = height_wrapper - height_info;
$('.wrp').css({
  'height': height_wpr
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.wrp {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"></div>
  <div class="info">Did you see the virgin on the rock <br>in a white robe over the waves<br>When, raging in the stormy darkness, <br>the sea Played with the shores,<br>When a ray of lightning lit up<br>Her hourly brilliance with scarlet <br>and the wind beat and flew<br>With
    her flying veil?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need jquery, only change in layer .wrapper display:flex instead display:block

```
 .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/tm493n1w/2/

Is that what you need?